# What does mean enableSingleRuntimeChunk in Webpack Encore?

Tags: webpack

If there is enableSingleRuntimeChunk option in my webpack config vuejs doens't work. Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `<script src="{{ asset('build/runtime.js') }}"></script>` in your application. That's probably the issue.